# Which path is possible to access from a custom MediaCas Plugin on Android?

Tags: android, android-emulator, cas, drm

I am building a custom MediaCas plugin for Android 8.0.0 and trying to run it on Android 8.0.0 x86 emulator on Windows host. My MediaCAS plugin needs to persist some data. I tried to use path of emulator's External storage(storage/emulated/0/Download/) as well as internal storage of application which tries to use the MediaCAS plugin (/data/data/{App Storage folder}). But the MediaCas plugin is unable to create a file in these paths due to PERMISSION error.

MediaCas Plugin library is loaded by "mediadrmserver" process on emulator and this process looks to run as 'media' user and 'mediadrm' group.

I found the folder "/data/mediadrm" on emulator which runs as 'mediadrm' user and group. But the MediaCas plugin failed to add a file to this path as well.

Any suggestions on which path can be used on Android emulator to be written and read from MediaCas Plugin is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default then MediaDrm service does not have permission to perform file system read/write operations. On Android emulator this can be enabled by setting the SELinux to permissive mode using following command. After doing this, my MediaCas plugin is able to read write to "/data/mediadrm/" path.

adb shell setenforce 0